# will specifying time evaluate will override timestep select by RK45 method? (scipy.integrate.solve_ivp)

Tags: python, scipy, runge-kutta

from

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html

with

```
sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method='RK45', t_eval=None, dense_output=False, events=None, vectorized=False, **options)
```

`t_eval` is optional for store solution in specify time.
Will this override timestep select by `RK45`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not override the timestep.  One way to verify this is to use `dense_output=True`, which saves data at each timestep for interpolating later.

The `sol` attribute contains additional information about the timesteps in the `ts` attribute.  Here, you can see that using `t_eval` changes the return of `sol3.t` but does not affect the timesteps.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

# To make readable
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

method = 'RK45'

def dy(t, y):
    return y

sol = solve_ivp(dy, (0, 10), [1], method=method)
print(f"No options    : {sol.t}")
sol2 = solve_ivp(dy, (0, 10), [1], method=method, dense_output=True)
print(f"Dense output  : {sol2.t}")
print(f"  Interpolants: {sol2.sol.ts}")
t_eval = [5]
sol3 = solve_ivp(dy, (0, 10), [1], method=method, t_eval=t_eval, dense_output=True)
print(f"t_eval return : {sol3.t}")
print(f"  Interpolants: {sol3.sol.ts}")
```

returns

```
No options    : [ 0.    0.1   1.07  2.3   3.65  5.03  6.43  7.83  9.24 10.  ]
Dense output  : [ 0.    0.1   1.07  2.3   3.65  5.03  6.43  7.83  9.24 10.  ]
  Interpolants: [ 0.    0.1   1.07  2.3   3.65  5.03  6.43  7.83  9.24 10.  ]
t_eval return : [5]
  Interpolants: [ 0.    0.1   1.07  2.3   3.65  5.03  6.43  7.83  9.24 10.  ]
```

I mildly suggest that instead of using `t_eval`, you should only use `dense_output=True` and then construct y_eval after the fact.  This is a much more flexible and transparent usage.

```
sol = solve_ivp(dy, (0, 10), [1], method=method, dense_output=True)
y_eval = sol.sol(t_eval)
```

Answer (score 0):

### For short answer

, No! it not override RK45's time step besause the function `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` will use interpulated value for each `t` in `t_eval`. And RK45 still use its own time step.

---

### For long answer.

After doing some investigate, I found that.
According to   [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py#L156-L587/)!

At line 156 in function `solve_ivp`. At line 477.

```
solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
```

The solver doesn't take `t_eval` as parameter.
At line 511.

```
t = solver.t
```

Solver return it own `t`.

At line 545.

```
if solver.direction > 0:
            t_eval_i_new = np.searchsorted(t_eval, t, side='right')
            t_eval_step = t_eval[t_eval_i:t_eval_i_new]
```

Which `t_eval_i_new` is new index of `t_eval` that have `t` in between using `np.searchsorted` and `t_eval_step` is time steps of `t_eval` between ode solver step.

```
if t_eval_step.size > 0:
            if sol is None:
                sol = solver.dense_output()
            ts.append(t_eval_step)
            ys.append(sol(t_eval_step))
            t_eval_i = t_eval_i_new
```

Which means we append `t_eval_step` to `ts` and use `solver.dense_output()` to interpolant over step and give approximate value for each specific time in `t_eval_step`
At line 585 after finish integration then program return output .

```
 return OdeResult(t=ts, y=ys, sol=sol, t_events=t_events, nfev=solver.nfev,
                 njev=solver.njev, nlu=solver.nlu, status=status,
                 message=message, success=status >= 0)
```